# Ignore div hidden in validation

Tags: javascript, css, jsp

I have a file .jsp with a div that I show/hide according to the value of a select.

If the value of my select is "no" hide the div and if is "yes" show the div

I use **ng-required** if a parameter is required for the validation.

But if the value is "no" and I validate my form, I can't validate it because the field in the div hidden **is empty**.

I test something but no result.

**CODE**

```
<div class="row" id="yesAuth">
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.basicAuthForBackendUsername, 'has-success': valid.basicAuthForBackendUsername}">
       <div class="form-group" >
           <label for="basicAuthForBackendUsername">basic auth username *</label>
           <input type="text" name="basicAuthForBackendUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="basic auth username" ng-model="api.basicAuthForBackendUsername" ng-required="true"> 
           <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.basicAuthForBackendUsername.required">basic auth username is required.</span>       
      </div>                                
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
      $("#basicAuth").change(function () {
      if($("#basicAuth option:selected").val() == 'yes'){
          $('#yesAuth').show();
      }
      else{
          $('#yesAuth').hide();
      }
      });
   });

$("#basicAuth").validate({
     ignore: ".hidden"
});
```

**CSS**

```
<style media="screen" type ="text/css">
    .hidden {
       visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

How can I fix my problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Please use angular validation and use ng-if for show and hide a div.
In case of angular you don't required to use JS code.

You can easily do in angular using ng-if="set you condition here"

And validation will not work when element is hide(Not display on DOM)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.removeAttribute()` when you hide the element and `.setAttribute()` when you show it (from plain old vanilla JavaScript).

```
$(function () {
      $("#basicAuth").change(function () {
      if($("#basicAuth option:selected").val() == 'yes'){
          $('#yesAuth').show();
          $('#basicAuthForBackendUsername').setAttribute("ng-required", "true");
      }
      else{
          $('#yesAuth').hide();
          $('#basicAuthForBackendUsername').removeAttribute("ng-required");
      }
      });
   });
```

I am not familiar with AngularJS so please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I test something like that but now if the value is "yes" and I validate my form the field is not checked whereas it's empty..

```
$(function () {
    $('#yesAuth').hide();
    $("#basicAuth").change(function () {
               if($("#basicAuth option:selected").val() == 'yes'){
                            $('#yesAuth').show();
                            $('#basicAuthForBackendUsername').attr("ng-required","true");
                            $('#basicAuthForBackendPassword').attr("ng-required","true");
                            alert("VOILA" + $('#basicAuthForBackendPassword').attr("ng-required"))

                }
                else{
                            $('#yesAuth').hide();
                            $('#basicAuthForBackendUsername').attr("ng-required","false");
                            $('#basicAuthForBackendPassword').attr("ng-required","false");
                            alert("VOILA" + $('#basicAuthForBackendPassword').attr("ng-required"));
                }
     });
});
```